# .NET Excel Interop v15 and IIS 7.5 - Excel access error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, excel-interop

I have some trouble with the excel interop library v15 (Office 2013) and the IIS 7.5.

Using the library I want to open and read through an excel file, but breaking up already on method "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook.Open". I'm getting a COM Exception saying that excel isn't allowed to access the file.

I made sure that the IIS group has access to the desired file path and the file itself.
Also I used the corrupt load enum "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCorruptLoad.xlExtractData" and disabled notification on both, .open method and the Application instance.

I read through some articles saying that microsoft does not directly support automation concerning IIS and interop libraries such like word or excel interop. But that does not mean it would not work.

I can't figure out why excel is not able to access the file.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Greetz